# Java SOAP web service returning DataHandler

Tags: java, grails, soap

I'm trying to consume a SOAP based WS that returns a java DataHandler. I'm using grails and apache httpclient.PostMethod. If I use the soap tool, I am getting the file as an attachment (see img - BTW, soapclient.com has a great tool).

[image]

In my Grails controller:

```
class connectToSoap { 

def getFile = {

   def payload = """
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
   <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org    
      <userLogicalId>${params.userLogicalId}</userLogicalId>
      <clientLogicalId>${params.clientLogicalId}</clientLogicalId>
      </mns1:getFile></SOAP-ENV:Body> 
   </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>  // Summarized payload
   """
   def method = new PostMethod(url) 
   method.setRequestHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=antocha.zip")
   method.addRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream")
   method.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(payload))
   def client = new HttpClient()
   def statusCode = client.executeMethod(method)

   InputStream inputStream = method.getResponseBodyAsStream()
   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\var\\nfile.zip"))
   byte[] bytes = new byte[1024]
   while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
      out.write(bytes, 0, read)
   }
   inputStream.close();
   out.flush();
   out.close();

   method.releaseConnection()
}
```

When I run this, I get an exception with inputStream.read (groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property). I'm guessing the handling the attachment file should be handled differently?

Can anyone give me a example code using httpclient.PostMethod to make SOAP calls that returns a DataHandler? Thanks, I truly appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the requestHeader and it worked. I got the file being served by the SOAP service.

method.addRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml")
method.addRequestHeader("Accept","text/xml,application/xml;q=0.9")
method.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(payload))